# Microsoft Azure Hosting Servers

Tags: vps, azure

I currently have a Microsoft Azure subscription. Since this platform offers VMs, I thought to myself "Why not try to make a hosting company and sell these VMs from one big server?"

So there's my question, is it possible to host multiple VMs from one VM in Azure? If so, how would i do this...? A brief description will do if it's possible!

Answer (score 2):

Today, Microsoft Azure doesn't support nested virtualization, the technology required to run virtual machines inside other virtual machines.

However, this technology is being rolled out [with Server 2016 and Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting), so it *may* eventually become available.

Keep in mind that nested virtualization has a performance penalty which on modern hardware isn't very large, but is larger than virtualizing on bare metal hardware. Your best bet is still to virtualize on physical servers when possible.

Further, Azure limits the number of global IPv4 addresses you can use, and VMs you resell to customers will need their own separate global IPv4 addresses. Moreover, Azure doesn't support IPv6, which is a critically important feature in the market you are proposing to operate in.

In short, Azure is a poor fit for what you want to do.